# Creaing a Pyramid shape using only CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a pyramid like shape in CSS. *I am doing it with a method I read about on internet that when you set the width of a Div to 0 px its borders will join creating 4 triangles.* But I want to remove/cut the pointed tip of the pyramid and I have been unable to do it. I tried hiding tip with other DIV but that does not looks right.

**Present shape:**
Below is what I have made so far.

[image]

**Required shape:**
What I want to make is a shape like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
#pyramid {
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 20px dotted transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="pyramid"></div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding any width to your div will do the trick. Doing so, you'll in fact have 3 connected figures: 2 triangles and 1 rectangle in between.

```css
#pyramid {
  width: 5px;
  border-left: 20px dotted transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="pyramid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `perspective()` and  `rotateX()` to create shape like this

```css
.pyramid  {
  width: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  transform: perspective(6px) rotateX(11deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="pyramid "></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've placed a small white triangle at top edge of a Big blue Triangle

```css
.triangle {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 50px 150px 50px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
 position: relative;
}
.triangle::after {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: -1px;
 left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"> </div>
```

Here is [the link to css triangle from CSS-Trick.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Else you can generate easily using [this online APP](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)